# How to forcibly call interface implemented method?

Tags: c#

Considering: EqualityComparer.Default Property, its written in MSDN that:

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the
>   System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an
>   EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of
>   Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

My Understanding:
As it will return EqualityComparer "object", So it should call overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T(if it overrides or Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode, otherwise). 
How could it call implemented method of IEquatable? Is it doing it forcibly? If yes, HOW? Correct me if i am wrong.

Here's the MSDN Link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in a generic class as follows, actually the right method (`IEquatable<T>`) would be selected anyway:

```
    private class MyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }
        // Hashcode...
    }
```

Whereas if you cast y to `object`, the reference would be to `object.Equals`. This is just an overloaded method, and so that is resolved at compile time.